# protractor can´t start firefox

Tags: jasmine, protractor

protractor can´t start firefox:

Can you help?

```
at protractor.conf.js, I have:

capabilities: {
'browserName': 'firefox' 
}
```

With chrome works fine.

```
[12:40:28] I/update - chromedriver: file exists         Z:\GIT\biblioteca_app\Neadvance\ClientApp\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.40.zip
[12:40:28] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.40.zip
[12:40:28] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.40.exe up to date
(node:190100) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use     os.tmpdir() instead.
[12:40:29] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:40:29] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[12:40:29] E/direct - Error code: 135
[12:40:29] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run     'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[12:40:29] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run     'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
at Direct.getNewDriver     (Z:\GIT\biblioteca_app\Neadvance\ClientApp\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:91:31)
at Runner.createBrowser     (Z:\GIT\biblioteca_app\Neadvance\ClientApp\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
```

The above issue is when i run "ng e2e" in visual studio.

If i run "protractor protractor.conf.js", i have a diffent issue:

```
(node:194784) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[13:24:14] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:24:14] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
Jasmine started
Biblioteca App
× Validate Main layout
- Failed: waiting for page to load for 10000ms
 Wait timed out after 10000ms
 Wait timed out after 10000ms
```

Comment: Did you run the command it's telling you to run? `webdriver-manager update`

Comment: Yes, i did. 
Still have the same problem.  This happens when running "ng e2e" on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the soluction for this problem is in "https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4868#issuecomment-403003116"

I can't confirm my answer. 
If you time, confirm it.